# How to add leading zeros with fixed length and pre-defined number set in SublimeText 3

Tags: text, formatting, sublimetext3

I have several whole numbers of varying lengths/widths. Sample set below:

`490`
`29`
`0924`
`29`
`1`

I'm looking for a convenient way in SublimeText 3 to transform them so that each has a leading zero and the total width is 5. I know Excel has this feature: Select column > Format Cells > Custom > (type in five zeros) > Viola!, but need a solution in SublimeText.

`00490`
`00029`
`00924`
`00029`
`00001`

I have tried using the the Sublime Text `Insert Nums` and `TextPastry` plugins but could not figure out how to do it.

With TextPastry, I did: 
`~05` in the command line, which would get the formatting right but would start me off at 1, thus creating `00001`,`00002` etc. I need a way to tell it to work it's way down the list I've already provided, not create one from an index. I thought `\i` would do this kind of iteration but apparently it start the index at 1.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Insert Nums` can do that.

1/ Select your existing data:

`490
29
0924
-29
1`

2/ Split your selection into multiple lines (`cmd+shift+l` or `ctrl+shift+l`)

3/ Go into `Insert Nums`

4/ Use this input: `i|~=05::_`

5/ Result:
`00490 00029 00924 -0029 00001`

Explanations:

- `i` is used to say you're actually reading integers (`f` for floats)
- `|` means you are using existing, selected data
- `~=05` is the zero-padding to a length of 5 (`=` is actually unnecessary here)
- `::_` is the expression, in this case, `_` is for "use the data as it is"

Let me know if you have any issue with this.

--Alexis

Comment: Alexis, This is perfect! And thank you for the straightforward explanation. You know, I'd really like to get better at these expressions because they're powerful but I feel like I would need a simplified (interactive) tutorial. Let me know if you can recommend any resources. The Github page for Insert Num is alright but looking for something more simplified with more comprehensive examples/use cases. - Thanks again!

Comment: Sure no problem.
I don't know of any tutorial for this though. InsertNums in this case is great because it's live, but I had to go through trials and errors on this one, because I'm not so good with this either...

Comment: Here's the [documentation for Insert Nums](https://github.com/jbrooksuk/InsertNums).

Comment: It´s kind of weird that ST doesn't have a native resource for that.